# Is there a way to programmatically do a "save as " on an init.nb file to save it as init.m?

Tags: front-end

I am using Mathematica 8.0.4.0 running under Windows 7. Is there a way to programmatically do a "save as " on an init.nb file to save it as init.m?

In the documentation center under tutorial/FrontEndTokens I found

```
FrontEndExecute[{FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"SaveRenameSpecial", "Text"]}]
```

but it doesn't seem to work? I am looking for a working variation of this where "Text" is replaced by "Package" or somesuch.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To confirm, `File > Save As...` and `Mathematica Package (*.m)` manually does what you want, correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I should have made that more clear. Maual `File>Save As...` and `Mathematica Package (*.m)` works fine and is exactly what I would like to achieve programmatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct token syntax appears to be as follows:

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEndToken[
   FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
   "SaveRename",
   {"C:\\Data\\TestFile.m", "Package"}
 ]
]
```

This more compact form also works:

```
FrontEndTokenExecute[
  FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
  "SaveRename",
  {"C:\\Data\\TestFile.m", "Package"}
]
```

Please note that:

- This is equivalent to doing `File > Save As...` select `Mathematica Package (*.m)` manually and will save *only* the Initialization cells of the Notebook.  (The other cells are saved as `(* comments *)`.)
- If you do not provide a file path the file will end up in `$HomeDirectory` which is not usually where you want it.
- No warning message is issued if the file cannot be saved.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Robert I'm glad I could help.  Finding these sometimes requires a bit of wizardry. ;-)

Comment: It seems like this may no longer be functional. At least for Mathematica 11.0.1 on a Mac the command does nothing. Both `"SaveRename"` and `"SaveRenameSpecial"` bare will open the dialogs, but passing a file name seems to do nothing.

Comment: @MB1965 Thanks for the note.  I am still using 10.1.0 and run Windows so I cannot attempt to find a solution.  If this is important to you please post a new question with a link back to this one, and note the version specific problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it turns out it merely doesn't like the ~ shell escape that's the standard on Unix. If I give it an absolute path the package generates fine. No idea why I didn't check that earlier.