# How to "save as" a notebook programmatically, given a path string?

Tags: front-end

## How to "save as" a notebook programmatically (from within the notebook), given a path string?

here is a path string (it specifies the new name and location of the new notebook)

```
path="/home/conor/myNewNoteBook.nb"
```

I have tried many commands but none seem to work. I reckon it is something similar to this.

```
FrontEndExecute[
    FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], {path, "Notebook"}]
 ]
```

Unfortunately this [similar question's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-do-a-save-as-on-an-init-nb-file-to-save-it) doesn't work for me. (Maybe its because I'm using linux?)

Comment: Unless you *just* want to save the notebook to a different location, in which case `NotebookSave` is your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Expanding b3m2a1's comment...

```
path = "/home/conor/myNewNoteBook.nb";
NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], path]
```

this can be made into a function, which can be auto loaded on start up, saving the user from having to use the mouse.

Comment: If this is what you need I see no reason not to accept it so the question can be tagged as satisfactorily answered

Comment: Thanks, (it won't let me tag it for 2 days). I'll tag it in 2 days time.