# How to programmatically save tagged cells from currently open notebook (nb ext) as a package file (m ext)?

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, kernel-startup, initialization

Please do not tag this question as already answered because the method described at [Is there a way to programmatically do a “save as ” on an init.nb file to save it as init.m?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-do-a-save-as-on-an-init-nb-file-to-save-it) is only for saving entire contents of notebooks. I wish to be able to save selected cells.

I often need to make edits to an `init.m` file which I have saved in two locations (`FrontEnd`,`Kernel`) in the `$UserBaseDirectory`. Doing this manually becomes quite cumbersome so I am looking for a quick and easy programmatic way of doing this.

I do all edits on `init.nb` and then manually do a Save As `init.m` to the two aforementioned locations. Ideally I only wish to save tagged cells from the currently open notebook (`init.nb`). Unfortunately I am very new to programmatic notebook operations so I am having great difficulty figuring this out.

As a *proof of concept* I wish to save the full contents of a list of tagged cells as a package file to a given temporary directory `dir`.

```
cells = Cells[CellTags -> {"paths", "packs", "tasks"}]
dir = FileNameJoin[{$Home, "tmp"}]
file = FileNameJoin[{dir, "tmp.m"}]
```

The following work but only for the entire contents of notebook...

```
FrontEndTokenExecute[
 FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "SaveRename", {file, "Package"}]
```

I also tried this which again works only for entire contents of notebook...

```
FrontEndTokenExecute[
 FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], "SaveRename", {file, "Package"}]
```

Please help. I tried many different things shown in official documentation and did learn a lot unfortunately nothing that addresses this problem.

Comment: Does `FrontEndTokenExecute[Notebook@NotebookRead@cells, "SaveRename", {file, "Package"}]` work?

Comment: @CarlWoll Sorry i was too busy to respond sooner. yes  thank you for this suggestion. it works almost perfectly except that every time i use it also pops up an Untitled (file with no extension). How do I suppress this ?behavior?